# Why does my Listview show large spaces even it has little text?

Tags: android, listview

In some `ListView`'s holder I got empty spaces even it has a small text in it.
`TextView` is set to `wrap_content`. My listview layout xml item has several buttons. I just set these buttons VISIBILITY.GONE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="photo"
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/left" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/right" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/answer"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:id="@+id/ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your list item layout xml.

Comment: remove spaces from your rowView xml file(which you are inflating in adapter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the root as `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` for the height.

What will happen in a vertically scrolling listview (read, infinite height available for children) if it's children say they want `match_parent`?

Can't see your image, but in a RecyclerView, each item's height would be the height of the RecyclerView.

Comment: @IriskulTurduev can you mark the answer as correct if it's working as expected? Click on the check mark next to the voting buttons to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using "match_parent" in the top  use "wrap_content" for height